# AngularJs block ulr navigation when user is not logged in

Tags: angularjs

I have to allow user to access application when user is logged in
and if user is not logged in then user should not be able to access the application by simply redirecting through **url**
In above case user should redirect to **login** page if he is not logged in

I tried in below way

```
$rootScope.tempObj = false;

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
if($rootScope.tempObj) {
       return;
} else {
    $state.go('login');
    event.preventDefault();
  return;
}
});
```

Here i am doing `$rootScope.tempObj = true` in login success callback

But I am getting an error - **RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

- My question is how to block url redirection if user is not logged in..
- and allow few state like forgot password, reset password, etc without user logged in

Answer (score 0):

use it with the `event.preventDefault();`

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
    if ($rootScope.tempObj) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if (!$rootScope.tempObj) {
        $state.go('login');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

check the similar [question](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2286)

Comment: Thanks, But If i am using `$state.go` inside `$stateChangestart` then its showing ERROR - **RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded** or is there any other way using AuthFactory or something?

Answer (score 0):

i think this way isn't perfect way to check user, if your application deals with backend by sending http requests you should test user privileges from $httpProvider, so in $httpProvider if you get a http code in 400 range, you should redirect user to login page,
i'll put a snipping code to do this

```
 .config(["$httpProvider", "$cookiesProvider", function($httpProvider, $cookiesProvider) {
    $cookiesProvider.defaults.expires = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 120 * 60 * 1000).toString();
   // $httpProvider.defaults.timeout = 50;
    var interceptor = function($q, $rootScope, $injector, $location, $filter) {
        return {
            request: function(config) {
                return config;
            },
            requestError: function(config) {
                return config;
            },
            response: function(res) {

                return res;
            },
            responseError: function(res) {
                var AUTH_EVENTS = $injector.get('AUTH_EVENTS');
                var $toastContent = $('<span>' + $filter('translate')(res.data.message) + '</span>');
                if (res.status == 403) {
                    $location.path('/logOut');
                }
                if (res.status == 402) {
                    $location.path('/home');
                    Materialize.toast($toastContent, 4000, 'danger');
                }
                if (res.status == 401) {
                    Materialize.toast($toastContent, 4000, 'danger');
                }
                // }

                return $q.reject(res);
            }
        }
    }
    interceptor.$inject = ["$q", "$rootScope", "$injector", "$location", "$filter"];
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
}])
```

Comment: I guess this is not useful for me, I want to block url navigation if user is not logged in. once user logged in to application then only user should be able to access application